# UILabel.frame.size.height shows less height than actual value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a UILabel with dynamic height by calculating the length of the text with this code:

```
UILabel *bankFullName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[bankFullName setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[bankFullName setMinimumScaleFactor:1];
[bankFullName setNumberOfLines:0];
[bankFullName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(240.0f, 20000.0f);
CGSize size1 = [[bankDetail valueForKey:@"FullName"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
bankFullName.text = [bankDetail valueForKey:@"FullName"];
CGRect fullnameFrame = CGRectMake(15.0, 15.0, 240.0, size1.height);
bankFullName.frame = fullnameFrame;
```

Now I don't have any issue with the code and the label is perfect. 
The problem is when I log `bankFullName.frame.size.height`, the height is not right. If the label has two lines, it gives the height of the label having one line and so on.
Any idea on how to get the accurate height of the label or if something I'm doing is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Font should be same for both, applied on uilabel and applied for calculating height.

Comment: Can you add to your code, where do you log the height?

Comment: `sizeWithFont:` was deprecated in ios7 so if this is running on ios8 that may be cause of the bad measurement . You should be using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just log the height of label in this method as `-[UIView layoutSubviews]`  get called when the size of the any view changes:-

```
-(void)layoutSubviews

{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   NSLog(@""... // log your label height to get the exact value.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `sizeWithFont:` to change the height of your label.
Use `[bankFullName sizeToFit]` instead. And don't forget to set the maximum number of lines to more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sizeThatFits:` to get correct size for UILabel, because `sizeWithFont` and `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` don't include UILabel padding.

```
CGFloat height = [self.bankFullName sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(240, MAXFLOAT)].height;
self.bankFullName.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 240, height);
```